# Xcode 10 beta SnapKit constraints type error

Tags: swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, snapkit

I'm using the Xcode 10 beta 5. My project is running on Swift 4 with the 4.0.0 SnapKit. 
I have a function which sets up `UITableView`'s constraints:

```
private func setupConstraints() {
    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.leading.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
        make.trailing.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        make.bottom.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    }
}
```

This function produces the following errors:
`Argument type 'NSLayoutXAxisAnchor' does not conform to expected type 'ConstraintRelatableTarget'`

I tried `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor as! ConstraintRelatableTarget`, but this casting fails.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try e.g. `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.leading`.  You’re missing the .snp part and the final part differs too.

Comment: `make.bottom.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.bottom)`
worked perfect. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Another Case

In my case, I get the same error when my "view" is *[optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional)* property. I was adding the ".snp" part like in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127922/4145420). But I get the same error.

#### Xcode Version 11.4 (11E146)

## Solution

So I converted to the non-optional. Problem solved for my case.

I hope, it'll help someone else.

Best.